# Listening to Android Package Installer

Tags: android

We know that we can launch an apk file, we can also listen the packages that has been installed, removed or replaced. But is there a way to listen to the package installer when the user chooses to cancel the installation? (this is when the package installer displays the permissions with install and cancel button)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is there a way to listen to the package installer when the user chooses to cancel the installation?

I am not aware of anything that gets broadcast in this case, sorry.